# How handle EPIPE when using axios and expecting a 413 response?

Tags: node.js, axios

When sending a too big file to an API I get:

```
Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:94:16) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

The server stops receiving the stream and giving a code 413. My app crashes ignoring any try catch block. As I understand it this is not try catchable. Is there some other way to handle these errors with axios?
Here is my code:

```
import axios from "axios"
import { sleep } from "./utils/sleep"

export const debugEpipe = async (event) => {
  // Fake a big file
  const fileSizeInMb = event.fileSizeInMb
  const fileContent = Buffer.alloc(fileSizeInMb * 1024 * 1024, 'a')
    .toString('base64')

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      '/some-endpoint',
      {
        attachments: [
          {
            filename: 'bigfakefile.pdf',
            filetype: 'application/pdf',
            data: fileContent,
          }
        ],
      }
    )
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("This will show.")
    await sleep(1000)
    console.log("This will not show. The EPIPE error halts execution.")
  }
}
```

Comment: https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors : `axios.post(...).catch(function (error) {...});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`EPIPE` error](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#common-system-errors) occurs when the Node.js process tries to write to a stream that has been closed on the other end: in this case, when the server decides the payload is too large and closes the connection.

You would need to implement error handling mechanisms at different levels of your Node.js application to handle the `EPIPE` error when using [Axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) and expecting a response like a [413 status code (`Payload Too Large`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413).

Since Axios is [promise-based](https://github.com/axios/axios?tab=readme-ov-file#promises), catching errors with try/catch blocks should work for most HTTP-related errors.

However, since `EPIPE` is a system-level error, it might not always be caught by the promise-based error handling in Axios (`try/catch` or `.then().catch()`): it can occur *outside* the lifecycle of the HTTP request as managed by Axios.
To make sure your application can handle such errors gracefully, you can implement global error handling in Node.js, capturing unhandled exceptions and unhandled promise rejections at the process level:

```js
process.on('uncaughtException', (error) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Exception:', error);
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Rejection:', reason);
});
```

[Axios interceptor](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) can be used to centrally manage HTTP request errors, including retry logic or error transformation before they reach the `.catch()` block or are thrown in an `async/await` context:

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  // Handle successful response
  return response;
}, error => {
  console.error("Intercepted error:", error);
  // Handle error
  // Optionally, tailor handling based on error specifics
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

That would not prevent `EPIPE` errors, but makes sure your application can log them and continue running without crashing.

The full code would be:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { sleep } from './utils/sleep';

const axiosInstance = axios.create();

// Add a response interceptor
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    console.error('Axios response error:', error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// Add a request interceptor
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    console.log('Sending request to:', config.url);
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    console.error('Axios request error:', error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export const debugEpipe = async (event) => {
  const fileSizeInMb = event.fileSizeInMb;
  const fileContent = Buffer.alloc(fileSizeInMb * 1024 * 1024, 'a').toString('base64');

  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.post(
      '/some-endpoint',
      {
        attachments: [
          {
            filename: 'bigfakefile.pdf',
            filetype: 'application/pdf',
            data: fileContent,
          }
        ],
      }
    );
    console.log('Response status:', response.status);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Local error caught:", e);
    await sleep(1000);
  }
};

// Global error handling
process.on('uncaughtException', (error) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Exception:', error);
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Rejection:', reason);
});
```

The code defines both a request and a response interceptor for an Axios instance.

- The request interceptor logs the URL to which a request is being sent before the request is made.
- The response interceptor logs errors that occur during the handling of responses. These interceptors provide hooks to handle or log requests and responses globally across all uses of the configured Axios instance.

For each request made with `await axiosInstance.post(...)`, a `try/catch` block is used to handle errors specific to that request. That allows you to handle errors that might be specific to the logic or context of that request, such as handling different types of HTTP response errors in different ways.

It also includes global error handlers for uncaught exceptions and unhandled promise rejections. These handlers make sure your application can log and react to errors that may not be directly related to Axios requests or that fall outside the control of local `try/catch` blocks and Axios interceptors.

Comment: Glorious! Can award bounty shortly.